# Image being stretched

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have an image that (fetched from our server) i want to place into a UIImageView. The image is 373x500. the UIImageView is 443x290 and the view is stretching it.

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 
                                                                         0, 
                                                                         500, 
                                                                         300)];

myImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
myImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewBackgroundColor];
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

NSLog(@"myImageView.image.size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(myImageView.image.size));
NSLog(@"myImageView.frame.size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(myImageView.frame.size));

[wrapperView addSubview:myImageView];
```

log reads:

```
2012-05-09 11:32:52.621[89145:1a303] myImageView.image.size: {373, 500}
2012-05-09 11:32:52.622[89145:1a303] myImageView.frame.size: {443, 290}
```

looks like:

[image]

shouldn't "UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit" tell it to keep its ratio and not stretch the image?

Comment: Having same issue now, never had problems before with contentMode before :S

Answer (score 1):

You should set `clipsToBounds = YES` on the view as well.

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` will **scale** the image (as the name implies) to fit the aspect ratio of your view.  If you don't want it to scale the image use `UIViewContentModeCenter` and it will just place the image, at its native size, in center of the view.

Comment: imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: This is not true, at least it isn't currently, or at least what it seems you're implying is untrue. The image is scaled but the aspect ratio of the original image is maintained. Per the documentation "The option to scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent"

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was setting the content mode BEFORE setting the frame...

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
imageView.myImage;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(...);
[self.view addSubiew:imageView];
```